# Should we lock the "Ethereum" name question?

Tags: discussion

[How was the name "Ethereum" chosen?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4503/how-was-the-name-ethereum-chosen)

Should we eventually lock this question with:

Historical significance

This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. More info: help center.

?

It is similar to this locked question: [Who is the person behind Ethereum?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/156/who-is-the-person-behind-ethereum)

Comment: you don't explain what is your problem with the question. I do not see any. It is concise, of general interest and leads to a non opinionated objective answer. 
I will ask why testnet is called Morden now :-P

Comment: @RolandKofler I made a small edit; I agree with your points but seems this stackoverflow is generally for technical questions.  Separately, I just noticed that I've answered some questions after you, and that's why we're having some discussions :) I'm not trying to engage in any debate, or post after you, in case it seemed that way.

Comment: I'm not stalking you either ;-) seems that we decided this are the hours to answer some questions. 
Didn't know this is StackExchange is for technical questions only. I hope it is open also to economic theory and a bit of history can't harm

Comment: I think it's up for discussion and that's why we have this meta.  imho your suggestions are fine

Comment: I think it should be locked, except that i got the answer mouahahahahaha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions can be historically locked when:

- The post is *Off-Topic* or *Not Constructive*, and
- The post is stellar, in spite of its off-topic nature, and
- There are a large number of views, upvotes and inbound links on the post, and
- The post is contentious; e.g., it has been closed and reopened at least once, or deleted and undeleted at least once.

I don't see how this question is off-topic on this site and I disagree that stack exchange network is only for technical questions. I'd say leave it open as it is clearly on topic and constructive. (And interesting, didn't know the World of Warcraft link!)